# Join two dataframe

Tags: r

I have to collect values from one dataframe and place in another. I have tried to use merge function but that mess up order in second dataframe.

This is how my data looks like.

```
> df<-as.data.frame(cbind(letters[1:4],1:4))
> df
  V1 V2
1  a  1
2  b  2
3  c  3
4  d  4

> dflist <- data.frame("home"= sample(df[,1],15, replace = TRUE))
> 
> dflist$away <-sample(df[,1],15, replace = TRUE)
> dflist
   home away
1     a    b
2     a    a
3     d    c
4     d    a
5     c    c
6     a    c
7     b    d
8     b    b
9     a    b
10    b    d
11    b    a
12    a    a
13    a    c
14    c    b
15    d    a
```

Desired result should look like this.

```
   home away value1 value2
1     a    b 1 2
2     a    a 1 1
3     d    c 4 3
4     d    a 4 1
5     c    c 3 3
.
```

Outcome table will be lose its order if I use merge here.

Comment: Assuming you want to keep the order in `dflist`, you could create an index column (e.g. `dflist$idx <- 1:nrow(dflist)`, yes, there are many ways to do this, but this is just an example). Then sort the final result by the `idx` column.

Comment: Please use `set.seed` for the reproducibility of the sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
dflist[c("value1", "value2")] <- t(apply(dflist, 1, function(x) 
    c(df[match(x[1], df$V1),2], df[match(x[2], df$V1),2])))
dflist
   home away value1 value2
1     a    b      1      2
2     a    a      1      1
3     d    c      4      3
4     d    a      4      1
5     c    c      3      3
6     a    c      1      3
7     b    d      2      4
8     b    b      2      2
9     a    b      1      2
10    b    d      2      4
11    b    a      2      1
12    a    a      1      1
13    a    c      1      3
14    c    b      3      2
15    d    a      4      1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. But I get an error msg when I copy your text.

> dflist[c("value1", "value2")] <- t(apply(dflist, 1, function(x)
+ c(df[match(x[1], df$V1),2], df[match(x[2], df$V1),2])))
Error in if (inherits(X[[j]], "data.frame") && ncol(xj) > 1L) X[[j]] <- as.matrix(X[[j]]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: My apologize. Works like a charm :)

Comment: Glad to hear that :-)